# Display data in the blade from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

How could I display data from the database in certain tables in my view? Without foreach, because it would overlap me. I want to take an id and that will be displayed and if I click on another id, it will display what I want from the other id. Here's how I did it.

Controller:

```
public function viewUserQuestion() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('viewQuestion', compact('posts'));
    }
    else {
        return redirect('register');
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
<div class="mailbox-read-info">
    <h5 align="center">{{ $posts->title }}</h5>
    <h6> From userID: {{ $posts->user_id }}</h6>
    <span class="mailbox-read-time" align="center">Created at: {{ $posts->created_at }}</span></h6>
</div>
<div class="mailbox-read-message">
    <p>{{ $posts->content }}</p>
</div>
```

I must say that I have looked at other issues like this, but I can't get a tip?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="card-body p-0">
    <div class="mailbox-read-info">
        <h5 align="center">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
        <h6> From userID: {{ $post->user_id }}</h6>
        <span class="mailbox-read-time" align="center">Created at: {{ $post->created_at }}</span></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="mailbox-read-message">
        <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**EDIT:** If you want to return only 1 post, use this in your controller:

```
public function viewUserQuestion() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $posts = Post::where('id', 1)->first();
        return view('viewQuestion', compact('posts'));
    }
    else {
        return redirect('register');
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want just one, I want to return them all, but when I click on an id from a post, it will show in the display page only the contents of that id.

Comment: Your question is about presenting different views while you specify only one view. I suggest you dive into a tutorial like this one: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

Comment: Yes, but for a specific id to show my data, I will have the ids in a row and if I click on an id, I want to show me specific for that id, to which I refer.

Answer (score 0):

$posts is a collection so you have to iterate over it - example:

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <div class="mailbox-read-info">
    <h5 align="center">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
    <h6> From userID: {{ $post->user_id }}</h6>
    <span class="mailbox-read-time" align="center">Created at: {{ $post->created_at }}</span></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="mailbox-read-message">
    <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
  </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: If I use @foreach I will display my data for example twice from two different ids.

Comment: You return all posts from your database. You could also leave your view intact and use `Post::first();` instead of `Post::all();`